# How computer stores 0.000000f according to IEEE 754 floating point representation?

Tags: floating-point, precision, cpu-architecture, ieee-754

As we know that we can represent any floating number in IEEE 754 floating point representation.But, in all the floating number we get something like 1.(some mantissa) * 2^(some exponent) where 1 is always fixed at first position and thus we assume it while converting back any IEEE 754 floating point number to decimal number.But what will we assume in case of 0.000000f as in that case we can not represent the number in 1.(some mantissa) * 2^(some Exponent) as it can never have 1 in starting of mantissa except 0.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format is very good, well written and detailed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The all 0's pattern is reserved for 0:

```
              3  2          1         0
              1 09876543 21098765432109876543210
              S ---E8--- ----------F23----------
      Binary: 0 00000000 00000000000000000000000
         Hex: 0000 0000
   Precision: SP
        Sign: Positive
    Exponent: -127 (Stored: 0, Bias: 127)
   Hex-float: 0x0p+0
       Value: +0.0
```

Note that there are two 0's in the IEEE representation: +0, and -0; which can be distinguished. The pattern 0x80000000 is used for the latter:

```
              3  2          1         0
              1 09876543 21098765432109876543210
              S ---E8--- ----------F23----------
      Binary: 1 00000000 00000000000000000000000
         Hex: 8000 0000
   Precision: SP
        Sign: Negative
    Exponent: -127 (Stored: 0, Bias: 127)
   Hex-float: -0x0p+0
       Value: -0.0
```

Comment: Note that biased-exponent = 0 implies a leading `0` bit for the mantissa; as Sneftel and chux point out, `+-0.0` is a special case of a subnormal (aka denormal) number.  Not a separate special case of its own the way +-Inf vs. +-NaN is where 0 vs. non-zero mantissa means something different with an all-ones exponent.

Answer (score 4):

> How computer stores 0.000000f according to IEEE 754 floating point representation?

When a `float` is smaller than the smallest normal non-zero `FLT_MIN` (`0 00000001 00000000000000000000000`), it is stored with a encoded biased exponent of 0  (`s 00000000 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`).  The implied bit is no longer 1, but 0 and the effective biased exponent is 1.

When `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx` is all zeros, the value is a +0.0f or -0.0f.

---

A `float` with the  encoded biased exponent of 0 and `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`  not zero, it is a *sub-normal*.

`FLT_TRUE_MIN` is `0 00000000 00000000000000000000001`, the smallest positive non-zero value.

Answer (score 2):

As Alias answered, "all exponent and significand bits set to zero" is defined as a zero. It's also possible to see zero as a special case of [denormal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number). When all exponent bits are set to zero (the smallest possible exponent), there is no leading 1 assumed for the mantissa, so if the significand is also zero then the resultant value (interpreted as a denormal number) is zero.